# php, create 1 array from another 2

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this:

```
$a1 = ['A','B'];
$a2 = ['1','2'];
```

I need to have this new one (with the _ between the values):

```
$a3 = ['A_1','B_2'];
```

I know isn't difficult, but I'm pretty stucked, using `array_combine` and stuff.

Any help? thanks

Comment: array_map and concatenation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
for($i=0;$i<count($a1);$i++) {
    $a3[] = $a1[$i] . '_' . $a2[$i];
}
print_r($a3);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Best way to do this without using for loop :

```
$a3 = array_map(function($a, $b) {
return $a . '_' . $b;
    }, $a1, $a2);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$i=0;
$j=count($a1);
//to make a new array
for($i;$i<$j;$i++)
{
a3[$i]=$a1[$i].'_'.$a2[$i];
}
//to display
for($i;$i<$j;$i++)
{
echo $a3[$i];
}
```